# Why the texture in my SKSpriteNode gets removed when it's done animating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a SKSpriteNode, I'm Trying to animate it in my `touchesbegan` and the animation works fine but when it's done animating, the default texture for my SKSpriteNode is gone. My R.atlas contains images named R1,R2..R7 ,What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

```
@interface MyScene()
{
SKSpriteNode * rightTubeNode;
}
@property NSArray* rightTubeAnimationArray;
@end

@implementation MyScene
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
       SKTextureAtlas *rightTubeAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"R"];
       rightTubeTexture = [rightTubeAtlas textureNamed:@"R1"];
       NSMutableArray *rightAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
       for (int i = 1; i <= rightTubeAtlas.textureNames.count; ++i){
           NSString *texture =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"R%d",i];
           [rightAnimFrames addObject:[rightTubeAtlas textureNamed:texture]];
           }
       self.rightTubeAnimationArray = rightAnimFrames;
       rightTubeNode = [self createRightTubeNode];
       rightTubeNode.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2+rightTubeNode.frame.size.width/2,50);
       rightTubeNode.zPosition = 0.1;
       [self addChild:rightTubeNode];
    }
  return self;
}
- (SKSpriteNode *)createRightTubeNode
{
     SKSpriteNode *rightTube = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:rightTubeTexture];
     rightTube = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:rightTubeTexture];
     rightTube.name = @"rightTubeNode";
     return rightTube;
}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
       for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
           CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
           CGPoint nodesLocation = CGPointMake(location.x,self.frame.size.height/2);

           if (nodesLocation.x>self.frame.size.width/2) {
              SKNode *archerNode = [self childNodeWithName:@"rightTubeNode"];
              if (archerNode != nil){
                 SKAction *animate = [SKAction animateWithTextures:self.rightTubeAnimationArray
                                             timePerFrame: 0.02];
                 [archerNode runAction:animate];
              }
           }
       }
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "gone" ? After animation is done, the node's texture will be R7. What texture do you see actually ?

Comment: I see the Cross on a white background which appears when an image is nill, It doesn't show up the R1.png (which is the first image in the R.atlas and also the first frame of the animation). It shows up a red cross. @Whirlwind

Comment: Missing resource , okay. First, check your texture names, second, clear Simulator's content and settings (Simulator-> Reset Content and Settings) and try again. Also how do you create your atlas (using .atlas folder or assets catalog) ?

Comment: I'm not using assets catalog, I checked my files and file names and everything 4 times, they're all fine, I'm running my build on the device so no simulator reset thing needed. I've made a folder and renamed it to R.atlas (like always it should work fine) I've cleaned my build but the problem still exists. @Whirlwind

Comment: Okay,let me try to reproduce it. In the meanwhile, delete derived data, clean your project, delete an app from the device and build & run again.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate it. @Whirlwind

Comment: It works for me. I've created new project, created R.atlas folder with images named R1@2x.png, R2, R3 etc. and dragged atlas to the project ("copy items if needed" and "create groups options have been checked").

Comment: As last thing I can think of is to re-add your atlas. Before doing that, you should delete old atlas from project (right click on atlas, move to trash). Then, clean the project. This is the important part. So, delete, clean, re-add.

Comment: Ironically, Deleting and re-adding the R.atlas without any further changes did the trick, thank you. @Whirlwind It's very strange though.

Comment: No problem :) you are welcome , glad to hear it worked.

Comment: just to let you know, there is a restore setting when using animateWithTextures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-adding the R.atlas (with checking the Create groups options box) without any further changes did the trick, Thanks to @Whirlwind